# How to do calculation on previous date with given date in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have successfully calculate the rank of each column using windowing function.

i am trying to subtract the rank from the previous date; the record as below

[image]

I am trying to get the output like that

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE `test_a` (
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `x` decimal(39,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `x_RANK` bigint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `y` decimal(39,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `y_rank` bigint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

/*Data for the table `test_a` */

```
insert  into `test_a`(`date`,`id`,`x`,`x_RANK`,`y`,`y_rank``) values 
('2020-03-30',107,0.6477,2,0.8087,1),
('2020-03-30',112,99,4,8.9137,4),
('2020-03-30',110,0.0983,1,3.3885,3),
('2020-03-30',102,2.4444,3,2.7200,2),
('2020-03-31',112,0.2292,2,8.8220,4),
('2020-03-31',107,0.7146,3,0.8755,1),
('2020-03-31',110,0.1680,1,3.7388,3),
('2020-03-31',102,2.7215,4,3.3320,2);
```

Comment: If window functions are available then use LAG() for to get "previous" value.

Comment: if how to use lag with previous date; lag is worked with pre and post value. it can be work with date also? please help here

Comment: the difference of rank with the previous date that is 30 with the respective id.

Comment: i can get easily resolved by left join ; but it takes too much time ; can we resolved with LAG() function @Akina

Comment: @Akina please help here

Comment: Publish source data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts (or as a fiddle), not in screenshot form.

Comment: source data attached @Akina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT `date`,
       `id`,
       `x`,
       `x_RANK`,
       `x_RANK` - COALESCE(LAG(`x_RANK`) OVER (PARTITION BY `id` ORDER BY `date`), 0) diff_rank_x,
       `y`,
       `y_rank`,
       `y_RANK` - COALESCE(LAG(`y_RANK`) OVER (PARTITION BY `id` ORDER BY `date`), 0) diff_rank_y
FROM test_a
ORDER BY `id`, `date`;
```

[fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wGwjpE1ZpQAJSaAeWC6fuh/0)

You may add a condition which removes "first" rows per `id` from the output (for example, check that none `LAG()` is not null).

Comment: great sir , can we also subtract from max value of x  partition by id